# Cannot access Windows drive from Ubuntu 12.10 (USB)

Tags: ntfs

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my pen drive, in order for me to delete certain files of my Windows NTFS drive (I cannot boot in to Windows due to a file in there).
However, when I click on the drive in the Ubuntu file explorer, I am greeted with this unfortunate message:

```
Adding read ACL for uid 9999 to /media/ubuntu failed: Operation not supported
```

Comment: Open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T keys combo and give this command `sudo fdisk -l` post back the results , edit your question.

Comment: `/media/ubuntu` doesn't sound like the path where Windows would be mounted in linux unless the label on your Windows partition is "ubuntu". It would more likely be `/media/748388599828` (A NTFS/FAT UUID) or `/media/LOCALDISK` or `/media/OS` which are common partition names for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I just got exactly the same problem,my friend gave me the link,and the solution worked like a charm.

Apparently,some USB flashdisk just can't work with some USB 2.0 driver,so the solution is to disable `ehci_hcd`

here's the link:
http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-disabling-ehci_hcd/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.